# Is result of allocation in heap interdependent to result of allocation in stack?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Let's consider this code:

```
static const size_t DATA_SIZE = 100000;

void log_msg(const char* msg)
{
  char msg_buffer[DATA_SIZE];
  // Do something...
}

int main()
{
  // Do something heap-memory consuming...

  unsigned char buffer = new unsigned char[DATA_SIZE];
  if(!buffer)
  {
    log_msg("Insufficient memory!");
    return 1;
  }

  // Go ahead...

  delete[] buffer;

  return 0;
}
```

Now, let's imagine that at the moment of allocation memory in the heap for the `buffer` there is no free space AND, at the same time, there is enough free space in the stack.

My question is pretty simple: will allocation in the stack for the `msg_buffer` be ALWAYS erroneous if allocation for the `buffer` in the heap is erroneous?

As far as I know, the stack is allocated for each thread and the heap -- for process. So, is there any guaranty that result of memory allocation in the stack will not correlate to result of memory allocation in the heap? Of course, I don't consider the stack overflow in itself. In other words, is the memory which reserved for the stack actually reserved for it fully? Or could there be situations when for some reason during program execution this reservation can be shrunk?

If there are no platform-independent assertions concerning this then I could know whether there are ones for the case of Linux for x86 architecture.

Comment: There are no such guarantees, you should not depend on it. Stack and heap should be treated independently. For example you can predefine stack (os dependent) to be bigger than heap to begin with.

Comment: You can make buffer static to ensure that space is available even if you run out of heap space.

Comment: The C++ standard does not even refer to heap and stack memory.   Memory is allocated dynamically, statically, or automatically (if I've remembered all the possibilities).   In general, the answer to your question is therefore system dependent.

Comment: @freakish, I slightly confused by your comment. The word "independently" says me that they do not influence each other. But, on the other hand, you said: "There are no such guarantees" (that they will not correlate, I asked). I.e., they can correlate. So, which of your assertions is the right one?

Comment: @SergeRoussak There are no guarantees that they will correlate. That's what I wanted to say. Both can be arbitrarly large and they don't share any common space.

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly implementation dependent. By the way, the mere notion of stack and heap do not exist in standard even if they are common in real world implementation.

I can remember the good old MS/DOS systems where the allocation types could depend on the [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model). Some compilers used one single segment (SS) in small and medium models for both the stack and the heap, the stack growing from one end and the heap from the other, but used allocation from the memory above the program (so independent of stack) for compact and large models.

In the former case, if stack allocation was not possible, heap allocation was not either, but in the latter heap and stack allocation could succeed or fail independantly.

In modern OS using [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) like Linux, it is common to have a fixed size stack, and ask the OS for new free blocks for the heap. In that case, stack and heap allocation can succeed or fail independently